# How to disable overflow on body but not iframe (Meteor.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor, iframe

Im working on a Meteor POS project at the moment. (for people who don't know Meteor is a framework and can use javascript/jquery and all kinds of web app scripting). The application is suppose to be a full screen POS that does not need to scroll at all, but only the area which entered products needs scrollbar (iframe).

I ran into a problem that I don't know how to solve, which is how to disable overflow on the entire page but not the iframe. There are a few things I have tried but failed:

1. Setting body to overflow: hidden and iframe auto. Which of course it doesn't work because the entire body is not able to show the scroll bar and iframe is embedded within.
2. using onmouseenter (mouseover) and onmouseleave (mouseout) to listen for changes and using javascript or jquery to toggle between hidden or auto. I tried and even console logged but it doesn't want to work in meteor.js for some reason. Even if it worked I think the main page scroll bar will show too which I don't want.

[Here is an image, the top and bottom is part of the body and the middle part filled with items are using iframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKEVQ.jpg)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in CSS html, body {overflow:hidden} should do it, see https://jsfiddle.net/fhqdey6v/ (the main area is a div but an iframe instead of an div with overflow scroll behaves the same).

Comment: thanks, this is a better solution than using iframe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been answered by axel.michel in the comment.
It was a better solution overall than using iframe.

Thanks!